# zeroMQ (0MQ) startup multiple workers

Tags: php, ubuntu, ssh, zeromq

I have a controller that pushes received posts from a website into a socket that then is polled into a worker.php script, then it outputs to an results socket that is then dumped out to the "sink.php" and finally to the users browser.

How do I startup multiple worker.php files on the server so that I can confirm that the controller is correctly distributing the load?

Comment: Whats ZMQ pattern are you using? REP/REQ? SUB/PUB? etc